# Como submeter ao apertar ENTER em um QLineEdit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt-5

Tenho um determinado `QLineEdit` na minha aplicação que, quando um `QPushButton` é clicado, o texto do mesmo é enviado para o banco de dados.

Porém eu gostaria de poder adicionar esse mesmo evento ao apertar a tecla ENTER nesse `QLineEdit`.

Como posso fazer isso?

Meu código está mais ou menos assim:

```
 def buildUi(self):

    self.buttonSubmitText  = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Enviar")

    self.textChat = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

    self.buttonSubmitText.clicked.connect(self.onSubmitText)



 def onSubmitText(self):

    text = self.textChat.text()

    message = create_message(self.selectedUser["id"], text)

    formattedText = self._buildChatText(message)

    self.viewChat.insertHtml(formattedText)

    self.textChat.setText("")
```

No exemplo acima, quero que ao apertar ENTER em `self.textChat`, o método `onSubmitText` seja acionado.

Como faço?

**Observação**: Estou usando o Pyqt5, mas será bem-vindo respostas com Pyqt4, pra referências futuras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar o `returnPressed` para fazer isso, para conectares o evento ao método:

```
...
self.textChat = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
self.textChat.returnPressed.connect(self.onSubmitText)
...
```

Ou definir para que haja um trigger ao click no `buttonSubmitText` em vez de conectares com o método em si (mesmo efeito que `ele.click();` em javascript):

```
...
self.textChat = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
self.textChat.returnPressed.connect(self.buttonSubmitText.click)
...
```

Para que visualmente o botão possa ter aquele efeito tipico que conhecemos, botão a ser clicado, podes usar `animateClick` em vez do `click`.

[DOCS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#returnPressed)

Pelas pesquisas que fiz creio funcionar em Pyqt4 também.